# Attach flat mesh (or curve) to another mesh

Tags: modeling

Ok, this may be a total noob style question, but all the solutions I've found don't seem to cover this particular type of situation...

I'm creating a number of different types of glass bottles for a graphic design class, some curved, some with flat faces, etc.. (if it makes a difference, I'm using cycles). I have a logo that I created in illustrator (and exported as an svg and png) that I want to attach to the face of the bottles so I can experiment with how it would look both extruded out and cut into the already solidified surface.

So, my question is, how do I take the logo (in any format), and place it (with some level of precision) on the surface of the bottle, following the curve or angle of the face/area I'm placing it, to allow me to experiment with cutting it in (bool or extrude inwards) or pulling it out (again, extrude or bool) to create variations on the appearance. I don't just want to leave it flat (i.e. UV mapping), and don't want to have to overly subsurface to use as a bump map (i would also like to be able to bevel the edges on some variations or make other modifications). Finally, I would like to do it after I apply the solidify to the bottle mesh so that it doesn't affect the inside face of the bottle because I intend to 'fill' them with another mesh to simulate liquid (like the blender guru beer glass tutorial).

Happy to provide images to clarify what I mean if necessary, as well as further explanation of my idea if not totally clear. I just feel like I'm missing something easy here and overcomplicating the process...

Comment: A couple of carefully selected or created pictures/diagrams are a very effective way to communicate your problem. You will most likely get better help than what I am able to give.

Comment: Possible duplicate of: [Setup for a wine bottle with multiple labels](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/40901/setup-for-a-wine-bottle-with-multiple-labels/40970#40970)

Comment: Read also: [Using SVG to put label on bottle](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/23627/using-svg-to-put-label-on-bottle/23647#23647)

Comment: And: [How to add curve modifier to text?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/33434/how-to-add-curve-modifier-to-text/60958#60958) or [emboss a text onto curved surface](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/44758/emboss-text-onto-curved-surface/44820#44820)

Answer (score 0):

You could use a displacement modifier with the image texture.

Some examples of this are: [Extrude the outside of a cylinder using a grayscale image](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/49629/extrude-the-outside-of-a-cylinder-using-a-grayscale-image), [Creating a large landscape with accurately varied elevations](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/27933/creating-a-large-landscape-with-accurately-varied-elevations) and [Landscape topography from grayscale image](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/27451/landscape-topography-from-grayscale-image),

Given that you want to avoid changing the inside shape of the bottle, this might be useful, because it describes how only one side of the solid can be influenced: [How to make a perfectly flat bottom for 3D-printing topographic relief?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/29002/how-to-make-a-perfectly-flat-bottom-for-3d-printing-topographic-relief)

Answer (score 0):

If I get you right,

If you want to attach a curve to the glass, you can 1st select the Curve then the bottle and go to edit mode and select "Knife Project" in the Tool Shelf, the curve will create its shape on the bottle (For perfect projection, switch to front or other sides apart from 3D view)

If you want to attach a surface to another surface, you can combile " Lattice Modifier" with "Shrink wrap Constraint"